# Android sometimes I get android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package. Why?

Tags: android, exception, notifications

I have a serius problem with my notification.

Sometimes when my app post the same custom notification I get this error:

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package  com.packagename: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: ClassName(package=com.packagename id=0     tag=null notification=Notification(vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0,flags=0x22))
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1093)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3906)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:840)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:598)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What I have to do?

The notification contains only LinearLayout, TextViews and ImageViews and it works perfect most of the time.

There is a way to surround this error with try/catch so in this way android not stop my app?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 3):

1) http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/app/ActivityThread.java#ActivityThread

From here we can see that this error can arise only in the one case:

```
case SCHEDULE_CRASH:
throw new RemoteServiceException((String)msg.obj);
```

2)http://openstorage.gunadarma.ac.id/android/sdk/sdk_310712/sources/android-15/android/app/ApplicationThreadNative.java

```
case SCHEDULE_CRASH_TRANSACTION:
        {
            data.enforceInterface(IApplicationThread.descriptor);
            String msg = data.readString();
            scheduleCrash(msg);
            return true;
        }
```

So this error arises from the `ApplicationThreadNative`

You can try to track ahead and maybe you will find the cause of this error.